# What do you call someone who is ungrateful, only sees things negatively and never acknowledges you

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, descriptive-grammar

I am a team player and like to contribute.

When asked to take on a task. I always say yes and I never get a thank you. He never provides all the details to what he wants and then asks why I didn’t do it a certain way. He always asks for feedback and comments and then when provided he ignores the suggestion and picks on an irrelevant statement and never acknowledges your suggestion.

Example: I was sure if SUE should be the one to do the job so I looked into it. I found out that she is allowed or acceptable. So how do you feel about this execution process? A, then B, then C. HIS RESPONSE: “We never said that she couldn't do the job. We said that she is not held responsible”. ...... never even acknowledging my suggestion. In a sum, I replied and said that if he had no comments on my suggestion that he asked for, that I apologized for wasting his time. I never heard back from him. This is an ongoing thing. A person can say *cat* and he swore you said *dog*.

Comment: You can call them that you have a new job. That is always the best ;)

Comment: Hi Brittney, thanks for the interesting question. You might want to edit it though, since the spelling is incorrect. "Ungreatful" should be spelled "ungrateful."

Answer (score 1):

One word is **curmudgeon**. Here is an example use from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curmudgeon):

> Oh, he had the reputation for being a curmudgeon, and he didn't suffer
>   fools gladly, and often he seemed to have no tolerance for people at
>   all.

Comment: I agree - curmudgeon was my first thought as well, though curmudgeons can also be oddly lovable. Walter Matthau's character Max in *Grumpy Old Men* comes to mind.